# MySQL insert or update if more than one column has the same value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get my SQL query to update rows only if the insert values of two or more columns match existing rows else insert if the row does not exist.

My table has the following columns

```
id | device_id | ifIndex | ifDescription | ifSpeed.....
```

Lets say I have the following rows

```
id | device_id | ifIndex | ifDescription | ifSpeed.....
 1 |         1 |       1 | ether1        | 1000
 2 |         3 |       1 | ether1        | 100
```

I want my query to be like this:

If I insert a row with `1 | 1 | port1 | 100`, mysql must update the row based on the `device_id` and `ifIndex`

so compared to the first table, if I were to run the query, I'd want my table to look like:

```
id | device_id | ifIndex | ifDescription | ifSpeed.....
 1 |         1 |       1 | port1         | 100
 2 |         3 |       1 | ether1        | 100
```

I have checked around but cannot find what I am looking for but I think it has something to to with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

My current query I have tried to build:

```
INSERT INTO device_ports (device_id, ifIndex, ifDescr, ifOperStatus, ifLastChange, ifAdminStatus, ifSpeed, ifPhysAddress, ifMtu, ifType) VALUES 
(
    '".$device['id']."', 
    '".$device_ports['ifIndex'][$i]."', 
    '".$device_ports['ifDescr'][$i]."', 
    '".$device_ports['ifOperStatus'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifLastChange'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifAdminStatus'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifSpeed'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifPhysAddress'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifMtu'][$i]."',
    '".$device_ports['ifType'][$i]."'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE device_id='".$device['id']."', ifIndex='".$device_ports['ifIndex'][$i]."'
```

Comment: You are on right track; you will need to define composite `UNIQUE` constraint on `(device_id, ifIndex)`

Comment: Do you mean running `ALTER TABLE device_ports ADD UNIQUE(device_id);` AND `ALTER TABLE device_ports ADD UNIQUE(ifIndex)`? 

If that is what you mean, I have tried that, only some rows get inserted into the database. It does not work.

Comment: No. Please google composite Unique index.

Comment: I have done some googling and it has me quite confused now. Do you perhaps have an example for me or a link?

Comment: The separate constraints will not work for you, they would mean you could have only one entry with any particular device_id, and only one entry with any ifIndex. A composite version enforces uniqueness on the combination of values, allowing (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (3,1), (4,1) etc...

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/  ; check this official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: The mysql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) illustrate what it looks like in a CREATE TABLE on lines 6 and 16 of the second example.

Comment: have you tried REPLACE INTO syntax?